# Как выводить данные из базы данных sqlite в новую активность?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite, recyclerview

Пишу приложение, для ввода и вывода текста (что-то вроде текстового редактора). Текст вводится в 2 поля для ввода (одно для названия текста, другое для самого текста), затем сохраняется в базу данных SQLite, после из этой базы данных имена текстов добавляются в элемент RecyclerView. При щелчке на любом имене в списке RecyclerView открывается новая активность.
Как сделать так, чтобы в этой активности открывался текст, соответствующий имени, по которому щёлкнул пользователь?
База данных:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactDb";
    public static final String TABLE_TEXT = "text";

    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_TEXT = "text";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_TEXT + "(" + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," + KEY_NAME + " text," + KEY_TEXT + " text" + ")"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_TEXT);

        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Адаптер:

```
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

    import java.util.List;

    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        private List<TextRow> mDataset;

        // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
        // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
        // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
        public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            // each data item is just a string in this case
            public TextView textView;
            public MyViewHolder(TextView v) {
                super(v);
                textView = v;
            }
        }

        public MyAdapter(List<TextRow> myDataset) {
            mDataset = myDataset;
        }

        // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                         int viewType) {
            // create a new view
            TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_post, parent, false);

            MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            // - get element from your dataset at this position
            // - replace the contents of the view with that element
            holder.textView.setText(mDataset.get(position).name);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mDataset.size();
        }
    }
```

Активность элемента RecyclerView:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class postsList extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private DBHelper mDataBaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts_list);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_num);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        mDataBaseHelper = new DBHelper(this);

        if(this.mDataBaseHelper == null){
            this.mDataBaseHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        } 


        SQLiteDatabase db = mDataBaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "select name, text from text";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{});
        List<TextRow> myDataset = new ArrayList<>();
        if (c != null) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    int idName= c.getColumnIndex("name");
                    int idText= c.getColumnIndex("text");
                    myDataset.add(new TextRow(c.getString(idName),c.getString(idText)));
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            c.close();
        }

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

      @Override
public void onClick(View v) { //метода, отвечающий за передачу данных в другую активность

    SQLiteDatabase db = mDataBaseHelper.getReadableDatabase(); //чтение базы данных
    String sql = "select nane, text from textTable"; //получение доступа к данным в таблице
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{});
    int idIndex= c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(String.valueOf(R.id.rv_element));
    String s = String.valueOf(idIndex);
    String Name = c.getColumnName(idIndex);
    String Text []= c.getColumnNames();//возможно это то, что нужно
    String upName = Text[1];
    //  String upText = Text[1];
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, UploadText.class);
    UploadTextRow textRow = new UploadTextRow(s//,upText
    );
    intent.putExtra(UploadTextRow.class.getSimpleName(), upName);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

xml файл элемента RecyclerView:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_num"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Вспомогательный xml файл, отвечающий за составляющие элемента RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textSize="25sp"
     android:onClick="buttonText"
     android:padding="10dp"
    />
```

Активность, которая должна принимать данные (имя и текст) и выводить их на экран

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class UploadText extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tvView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_text);

        tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String fName = intent.getStringExtra("fname");

        tvView.setText("Your name is: " + fName);

    }
}
```

layout этой активности:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/UpText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Данные из БД выводяться в `RecyclerView` и по нажатию на `View` вы запускаете `Intent`. В этот `Intent` впихнуть данные, которые вам надо. А после открытия новой `Activity` получить их и вставить куда надо.

Comment: @Mako Storm, но как в этот Intent впихнуть данные, соответствующие имени, по которому щёлкнул пользователь?

Comment: У вас есть переменная public `TextView textView;`. Это же имя, если я правильно понимаю, вот его и добавьте в `Intent`.

Comment: @ Mako Storm, Вы меня не совсем правильно поняли, выводится должен текст, соответствующий этому имени, а не само имя (в базе данных есть id, имя и текст)

Comment: Хм, Вы можете в MyViewHolder вместе с именем получать текст, просто его никуда не выводить.  А использовать для передачи в `Intent`.

Comment: Не проще ли присваивать каждой записи _id , по клику передавать через интент id  и делать запрос в бд на вывод информации по этому id

Comment: @ Романыч, попробовал, но пока что не получилось (я добавил в код вопроса метод, в котором я пытаюсь передать данные из RecyclerView и класс, который должен принимать эти данные)

Comment: @Mako Storm, пробовал, но никак не доходит, как это сделать, в данный момент все мои попытки приводят к тому, что после щелчка на имени из списка приложение просто вылетает

Comment: Попробуйте не создавать отдельный метод `onClick()`. Просто в метод `onBindViewHolder` впишите `holder.textview.setOnClick...` и в нем уже реализуйте `Intent`.

Comment: @ Mako Storm, с этого момента, пожалуйста, поподробнее, сейчас пробую это осуществить, и пока что не доходит, что и как делать

Answer (score 2):

@Sem вы умеете читать базу по ключу, умеете выводить данные. 
Конечно качество кода тут вопрос второй, но сам факт.

В чем тут проблема? Вам нужно так же открыть активность и так же прочитать данные.
Основная ваша как вижу -  передать `_id` на вторую активность. 
Примеров миллион. `intent.putExtra("ключ", данные)`

То что вам нужно сделать выглядит так: - при открытии новой активности бросать на нее через Интент всего лишь  `_id` записи или какой либо ключ который вы используете. У второй активности принимать и получать этот `_id`, 
далее составить запрос в базу данных, в котором передавать этот id как параметр запроса и выводить полученный результат. Все это вы уже умеете делать.
Вот и все. 
Ваш код я бы немного разделил , так как там все намешано в кучу. Но это не важно на данном этапе решения проблемы. 
Так же 
Посмотрите по логам что возвращает ваш запрос перед отправкой в Интент и что приходит на вторую активность.

Answer (score 1):

Не советую делать `startActivity()` в адаптере, лучше сделать это в `Activity` или `Fragment`. Я так делаю, но это с java 8

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

   private Consumer<TextRow> listener;

   public MyAdapter(Consumer<TextRow> listener) {
      this.listener = listener;
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
      holder.itemView.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
          listener.accept(mDataset.get(position));
      });
   }
  ......
}


class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     ...........
     void setupRecyclerView() {
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(::onClick);
        ............
     }

     void onClick(TextRow texrow) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("key_textrow", textrow);
        startActivity(intent);
     }
}
```

ну или вместо `Consumer<TextRow>` можно создать собственный интерфейс `OnClickListener`с медотом `onTextRowClick(TextRow textrow)` в `MyAdapter`

Comment: Когда ввожу listener.accept(mDataset.get(position)), почему-то пробел после него подчёркивается красным
И ещё вопрос, YourActivity - это активность, в которой должны выводится данные? (то есть так, которая открывается при щелчке?)

Comment: @Sem может вы забыли точку с запятой поставить. `YourActivity` это activity c RecyclerView

Comment: Возникли небольшие проблемы: 
в строке  MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(::onClick); :: и ; подчёркивается красным
В строке intent.putSerializable("key_textrow", textrow); красным подчёркивается putSerializable
И  пока что, не до конца понял, к чему относится ключ "key_textrow"

Comment: Поменял putSerializable на putExtra, теперь красным подчёркнуто ("key_textrow", textrow), подскажите, пожалуйста, что с этим делать

Comment: @Sem ваш `class TexRow` должен реализовать интерфейс `Serializable`

Comment: Спасибо, сделал, а что делать со строкой  MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(::onClick);,  там :: и ; подчёркивается красным

Comment: @Sem а какой еррор там пишет?

Comment: при сборке вылетает error: illegal start of expression
По этой строке пока что не нашёл (в Logcat целая портянка ошибок, но указания на эту строку пока не вижу)

Comment: при наведении курсора на строку вылезает: ';' expected | unexpected token

Comment: @Sem скинь код activity где адаптер

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101471/discussion-between-sem-and-alex-lysun).